what is the curvature of a hyper-cycle if it lies at the distance of r from its central straight line?
There is a post about the curvature on the hyperbolic plane with several methods to derive such formulas. They arrive at curvature = 1/tanh(r) for a circle with radius r on a hyperbolic plane with curvature 1 and I think curvature = 1/(R•tanh(r/R)) for a circle with radius r on a hyperbolic plane with curvature of 1/R.
But what about the curvature of a hyper-cycle, with radius r on a hyperbolic plane with curvature 1/R?
I did try to use one of those methods: to render the curve on the Poincaré Disk Model in such way as to go through the centre of the Disk and use the Euclidean curvature of the curve representation at the centre of the Disk; if the Disk's radius is 1 and the hyperbolic plane's curvature is 1 than a Euclidean distance near Disk's centre is 1/2 of the distance being presented and the Euclidean curvature of a curve representation is 2 times the curvature of the curve being presented.
By the way I think if you prefer to (1) consider a hyperbolic plane with any curvature 1/R and (2) to render it on a Disk keeping the Euclidean representation distances near the centre equal to the distances being presented, you just use the Poincaré Disk with the radius of 2R.
What I got for the curvature of a hyper-cycle is
                     tanh(r/R)/R.

To that aim we can represent a hyper-cycle with a circle of diameter d=|OQ| through the centre O of the Poincaré Disk with the radius of 2R and represent its central straight line with a circle centred at Q and crossing the perimeter at the same points A and B as the circle that represents the hyper-cycle. Then r, the hyper-cycle's distance from its central line, is represented as ρ=d–|AQ|, and d²=4R²+|AQ|², so d=(4R²+ρ²)/2ρ. Now ρ=2R tanh(r/2R), so d/2 = R/tanh(r/R)∎
It looks good both for r→∞, the curvature → 1/R which is the curvature of any horo-cycle on a hyperbolic plane with curvature of 1/R, and for r→0, the curvature → 0 which is the curvature of any straight line.
But is it correct?

FYI: In a comment to this Math.SE question, @mr_e_man confirms that the curvature of a hypercycle of radius $r$ is $\tanh r$ (in a hyperbolic plane of curvature $-1$). The result also figures into this answer of mine about angles inscribed in hyperbolic circles and hypercycles, providing analogous formulas.
